# What's this grammar and meaning

Tags: grammar

I'm watching Chernobyl.
In episode 1

> What else is left but to abandon even the hope of truth and content ourselves instead with stories?

I can't understand this sentence.
I just think nothing is left but only to abandon is left.
But I can't understand what he is talking about.

Comment: Nothing is left but to abandon truth, and content ourselves with stories.

Comment: There was so much secrecy and disinformation about what exactly was happening that they'd given up even ***hoping*** to discover the truth. All they could do was "believe" in in "stories" that might seem comforting, but which they knew were probably just fiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*But* = *except*.

> *What is left but to abandon ....?*

is a rhetorical question. The meaning is

> *There is nothing left (for us to do) except to abandon ...*

**Edit**: *Abandon even the hope of truth and content ourselves with stories* is a rather poetic way of saying "give up any hope that we might be able to find the truth, and instead be satisfied with telling or hearing stories".

Comment: What ourselves means? It means they abandon by themselves?

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain further, @TingChoe